# Google Proximity Beacon API gives 403 unauthorised error

Tags: android, ibeacon, iot, eddystone, proximityapi

I am trying to consume Google's Beacon Proximity api. i have followed following steps to integrate them:

```
1) Signed up on Google Api Console.
2) Created new Project.
3) enabled Beacon proximity api and Nearby Api.
4) Generated Api key from Credentials.
```

Afterwards i invoke the following api:

```
 {
  "advertisedId": {
    "type": "EDDYSTONE",
    "id": "ABEiM0RVZneImaq7zN3u/w=="
  },
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "placeId": "ChIJL_P_CXMEDTkRw0ZdG-0GVvw",
  "latLng": {
    "latitude": "71.6693771",
    "longitude": "-22.1966037"
  },
  "indoorLevel": {
    "name": "1"
  },
  "expectedStability": "STABLE",
  "description": "An example beacon.",
  "properties": {
    "position": "entryway"
  }
}
```

with the follwing url:

```
https://proximitybeacon.googleapis.com/v1beta1/beacons:register?key=xxxx(my_api_key)
```

but the response says:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Unauthorized.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

what is it that i am missing..

```
I also tried to use Beacon tools app but after entering EID and all other credentials..the App crashes(on android), while it is not able to connect to my eddystone on Ios.
```

Comment: did you use you actual api key at the end of the url?

Comment: yes(i used actual value) i have just trimmed it here..otherwise it would have thrown invalid Api_key error

Comment: Hi, @AmritpalSingh I am facing same issue but i used api key into url from the same project in which i create OAuth ClientId. I checked through 
OAuth 2.0 Playground. When i called https://proximitybeacon.googleapis.com/v1beta1/beacons?key=(apikey) then getting Invalid api key. Have you found any solution then please let me know. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Found the Solution, API_KEY can be used only to Access already registered beacons and their Characteristics, while to Register and update we require ClientId and client Secret key and you can register it in OAuth2.0 Playground. 
it worked for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can Get a service token after creating an account service key on the google API Console. Then generate it with this code:

```
String token = null;

try{
    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(accesKey).createScoped
                    (Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userlocation.beacon.registry"));


    credential.refreshToken();
    token = credential.getAccessToken();

} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BeaconRegisterClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BeaconRegisterClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Then put it on the header of your call:

```
key: Authorization value: Bearer (your token here)
```

set the body of this call as beacon.json